# Why is devise not obeying route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

***Note: as usual with SO, I solved my problem in the course of clarifying it to ask it here! Solution is at end.***

Rails isn't sending devise invitation URL requests to the right place.

When I go to:

`http://localhost:3000/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=SOME_TOKEN`

the browser just redirects to root.

routes.rb is sending requests to my custom devise controllers, like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { passwords: 'passwords', sessions: "sessions", invitations: 'users/invitations'}
```

devise.rb has scoped views enabled:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

rake routes gives me:

```
accept_user_invitation GET /users/invitation/accept(.:format)  users/invitations#edit
```

and users/invitations_controller.rb is like:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def edit
    # Try to catch rails if it resolves to this method like i want it to!
    # It fails to get here, though.
    byebug # elsewhere in my code, byebug successfully acts as breakpoint
    super
  end
end
```

So why is it redirecting to root?

I've gotten it to resolve to my custom edit method, but ONLY by removing the invitations controller from `devise_for` AND renaming it (as "accept") and explicitly making it a route:

```
devise_scope :user do
  scope'/users' do
    get '/invitation/accept' => 'users/invitations#accept', as: 'custom_accept_user_invitation'
  end
end
```

In case this is a cacheing issue, I've erased my Chrome DNS cache, restarted rails server and redis-server, and run rake tmp:cache:clear.

***UPDATE: Solution***

The issue was that I was *already signed in* to my site using some other account, so when I would attempt to accept a devise_invitable invitation, devise would redirect me to root!

I logged out and tried the URL again, and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was *already signed in* to my site using some other account, so when I would attempt to accept a devise_invitable invitation, devise would redirect me to root!

I logged out and tried the URL again, and it worked fine!